# Weird if condition in c: if( ((void)(d), 0) ) {...}

Tags: c

I read Xen source code and saw something like this:

```
#define is_domain_direct_mapped(d) ((void)(d), 0)
```

is_domain_direct_mapped is then used in a if statement as follows (d is a pointer to a struct variable):

```
if( is_domain_direct_mapped(d) ) {...}
```

So after compiler replaces is_domain_direct_mapped with its definition, we have something like:

```
if( ((void)(d), 0) ) {...}
```

The above if statement is very weird to me. This is the first time I see this kind of statement. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: What is `d` in the code? May be hard to answer without knowing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s meant to always produce `0` but also evaluate `d`, in case it’s something with side-effects like `p++`.

As for why you would want to always produce `0`: [the implementation is different on ARM](https://xenbits.xen.org/gitweb/?p=xen.git;a=blob;f=xen/include/asm-arm/domain.h;h=8dfc1d1ec28ae77e0d72e28db46941ca9aab9b25;hb=HEAD#l33).

```
#define is_domain_direct_mapped(d) ((d) == hardware_domain && dom0_11_mapping)
```

Notice how `d` is evaluated exactly once here too.

Some discussion from when this was first introduced as confirmation – [Re: [Xen-devel] [PATCH v3 1/3] xen/x86: introduce is_domain_direct_mapped(d) as (0) on x86](https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-devel/2014-07/msg03122.html):

> When I've implemented this defined in common/memory.c, Jan told me to
>   use [1]:
>
> ```
> #define is_domain_is_direct_mapped(d) ((void)(d), 0)
> ```
>
> I suspect you want the same things here.

referencing [Re: [v4] xen/arm: Allow balooning working with 1:1 memory mapping](https://patches.linaro.org/patch/22523/#37262):

> And you'll want to make sure (even if unlikely to be needed in
>   practice) that you evaluate the macro argument exactly once in both
>   flavors, i.e. in the case here
>
> ```
> #define is_domain_direct_mapped(d) ((void)(d), 0)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

The left member (in your case `d`) is evaluated for its side effects and then discarded. The right member (`0`) gives the result.